# Querying sys.dm_exec_sessions and sys.dm_exec_connections without granting the VIEW SERVER STATE permission

Tags: sql-server

Normally I have ordinary users that connect to my SQL Server database and execute stored procedures in the schema named `myschema`.

If these users try to get data from tables of the database, they do not see any tables, but they can access the tables through a stored procedure in `myschema`.

Now I am querying `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections` and would like to have the same approach, but no, I have to grant the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to an user that is calling the `myschema.GetUserSessions` procedure!

After all I want that users only have access to some fileds of `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections`, not to the whole views, and only through this very stored procedure, but not directly.

Currently I am using a workaround that is checking the permission and returning an empty result set with the right data types:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.GetUserSessions
AS
    /* To be able to run this procedure an user should have VIEW SERVER STATE permission:
    USE master;
    GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [HOST\Username];
    */

    IF EXISTS(SELECT permission_name FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') WHERE permission_name = 'VIEW SERVER STATE') BEGIN
        SELECT
            ses.login_name,
            ses.[host_name],
            con.client_net_address,
            ses.[program_name],
            ses.login_time,
            ses.last_request_start_time,
            ses.last_request_end_time,
            con.net_transport,
            con.encrypt_option
        FROM
            sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
            inner join sys.dm_exec_connections con on con.session_id = ses.session_id
        WHERE
            is_user_process = 1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT
            login_name = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR),
            [host_name] = CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR),
            client_net_address = CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR),
            [program_name] = CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR),
            login_time = CAST(0 AS DATETIME),
            last_request_start_time = CAST(0 AS DATETIME),
            last_request_end_time = CAST(NULL AS DATETIME),
            net_transport = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR),
            encrypt_option = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR)
        WHERE
            1 = 0
    END
```

Honestly to say I do not like an idea of neither granting the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission to users nor saving the data from time to time to some intermediate table.

Comment: I suggest trying dba.stackexchange.com in the first instance... this is beyond normal developer SQL Server.

Comment: @Dale K: If you have moderator permission, could you move the question there please instead of requesting to close it. I have put effort into it and "Close" is just clicking a button.

Comment: My VTC **IS** a vote to move. I only have VTC the same as you, you can probably also VTC (move) and then it only needs one more. Copy and past is hardly any effort though?

Comment: @siggemannen: Well, I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but if there isn't one, then "yes".

Comment: The cert thing is the new hotness and is pretty neat in general, you do it once and then have access to all kind of easy rights management

Comment: @siggemannen - "New hotness" - implemented as far back as I can remember (SQL 2005?). Maybe in geological timescales?